# How does deleting values in the Firebase Realtime Database work?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When we delete a child value in Firebase Realtime Database, it counts as an exclusion, correct?

But when we delete a node with several children, does it count as just an exclusion too? or is each child that belongs to the node counted as exclusion?

I'll explain it better: supposing it has this structure in firebase:

[image]

Each firebase plan has an exclusion limit.

1) How many exclusions are registered if I do this below? I believe that 3 exclusions, right?

```
referenceOne = (...).child("1");
referenceOne.removeValue();
referenceTwo = (...).child("2");
referenceTwo.removeValue();
referenceThree = (...).child("3");
referenceThree.removeValue();
```

2) Now, how many exclusions are registered if I do this?

```
reference = (...).child("users");
reference.removeValue();
```

3 exclusions or 1 exclusion?

Comment: What do you mean by "exclusion"?  Could you link to some documentation?

Comment: Do you know Firebase's plans? Spark, Flame and Blaze? Each has limits such as reading, inclusions and exclusions, right? It is these exclusions that I am referring to. I need to know if when deleting a node with multiple children, only one exclusion or the same number of children as there would be in the node is counted.

Comment: I'm very familiar with the plans (though you should note that Flame doesn't exist any more).  I don't see anything on the pricing page, or anywhere in the documentation, about anything called an inclusion or exclusion, with respect to database access.  Do you have a link to documentation that describes these concepts?

Comment: Do you mean "write operations" by "exclusions"? If so, it may help to realize that Realtime Database quota are based on storage size and the amount of bandwidth used, not on the number of write operations.

Comment: Doug Stevenson, here is the documentation link. It is shown that in the free plan, for example, the maximum is 20,000 exclusions. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas?hl=en

Comment: Frank van Puffelen, this link above shows the exclusions I am referring to. I was just wondering if deleting a tree with several children at once is cheaper than deleting each child one at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up Firebase database products.  The documentation you linked to is for Firestore, but the code you're showing is working with Realtime Database.  They have very different billing structures.  What you linked to has no relation to what you're actually doing.

Realtime Database doesn't charge you for individual writes like Firestore does.  If you want to know how Realtime Database bills you, read its [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing).  You can delete as much data as you want without getting billed.  You are billed primarily for **data downloaded** and **data stored**.

Comment: Wow, I was really looking at the wrong documentation. Thank you, I will see the correct documentation.